# How to display username next to message in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chat

I have built a simple chat application by following this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nRP91C1uX-w. On top of that, I have added a simple user authentication system using the clearance gem. I want to add a way to display the clearance account logged in next to the message sent by the user. 
For example something like this -> test@gmail.com: Anyone online?

I have tried finding tutorials on how to do this but it just comes up with irrelevant videos that don't help my cause.

Comment: Please add a link to the tutorial to your post and/or your code.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.  It is always better if you can add code to your questions, it helps with context, especially since links alone might not exist in the future.

That tutorial is really basic, highlighting the ActionCable and js features alone, but adding the user isn't too tough.

#### #1 Add a migration to attach the user to the message model

```
rails g migration add_user_to_messages user:belongs_to
```

Edit the migration to allow for no user (you might change this later)

```
def change
  add_reference :messages, :user, null: true, foreign_key: true
end
```

Add messages to the user.rb model

```
has_many :messages
```

Add user to the message.rb model

```
belongs_to :user, optional: true
```

Migrate

```
rake db:migrate
```

#### #2 Add the user to the form

(app/views/landing/index.html.erb in the tutorial)

```
<%= form_for @message, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.try(:id) %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

#### #3 Permit the user in the messages controller

```
def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:content, :user_id)
end
```

#### #4 Send the email address with the message in the ActionCable

(after the message has saved app/controllers/messages_controller.rb)

```
  ActionCable.server.broadcast('room_channel', content: @message.content, user: @message.user.try(:email))
```

#### #5 Pass the user data through the JS on new messages

(append the user to the html that is passed when a new message is created, in the channel js)

```
received(data) {
  $("#msg").append(`<div class='message'>${data.user} - ${data.content}</div>`)
}
```